# Jquery autocomplete httppost actionresult not loading after ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

So i've been searching stack for hours and cannot seem to find a solution.  I'm trying to implement a basic jquery autocomplete, but when i click/select the item in the autocomplete dropdown to send me to a new page, my httppost actionresult isn't returning the view.  It runs through the httppost controller fine (all paramaters are passed,queries run, models are passed to views, etc).  I'm pretty sure it's due to the `window.location.reload();` in my ajax post, but can't seem to figure this one out.  I also tried `window.location.href = link;` but that wasn't working either.  Please help :(

**JS**

```
$("#queryTypeInput").autocomplete({
  source: "/Dashboard/EnterMatterFormAjax/",
  select: function (event, ui) {                
    var inputVal = ui.item.value.substring(0, 10);                            

    $.ajax({type:"POST",
    url:"Dashboard",
    data:{ queryType: queryTypeval }, 
    success: function (result) {
      window.location.reload(); //this is where i think the issue is 
    }
  })
});
```

**EnterMatterFormAjax Controller (WORKING FINE)**

```
public JsonResult EnterMatterFormAjax(string term)
    {
        var termReq = Request["term"];            
        var termReq2 = "";
        if (termReq.All(char.IsDigit))
        {
            termReq2 = termReq + "%";
        }
        else
        {
            termReq2 = "%" + termReq + "%";
        }
        var ajaxMatterData = GetAjaxMatterData(termReq2);

        return Json(ajaxMatterData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**Index Controller (WORKING FINE)**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string queryType)
    {
        ...goes through code logic...
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `window.location.reload();` inside the autocomplete select event ? you want the page to reload ?

Comment: What is the new page you want to navigate to ? What data you want to pass to it ?

Comment: @Shyju after the select, i want the page to load the information in the [HttpPost]Actionresult Index.  Reload was just my last failed attempt.

Comment: when you select an item from dropdown list, instead of using ajax, use window.location.href = "/dashboard/index?queryType=" + queryTypeval

Comment: @KarthikMR for some reason the `window.location.href`wasn't acting as a post in visual studio? not sure why.  my edited answer solved my issue though

Comment: window.location.href will make a GET request. but in your Index action is decorated with [HttpPost]

Comment: @KarthikMR i tried what you said and changed my index action to `[HttpGet] public ActionResult Index(string queryType)` but now messes up my regular `ActionResult Index()` action.  the get actionresult is being called everytime

Comment: Change your Index action method name. eg. public ActionResult GetSearchPage(string queryType){//code}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just resubmitted my form after the autocomplete select instead of using the `window.location.href` as @KarthikMR mentioned.  I would have had to change around my controller actions, so i just took the simplest road. @KarthikMR suggestion did work though when i changed my actions, so this is a viable option! updated js below:

```
$("#queryTypeInput").autocomplete({        
source: function (request, response) {
    $.post("Dashboard/EnterMatterFormAjax", request, response);            
},
select: function(event, ui){            
    $("#queryTypeInput").val(ui.item.value);
    $("#enterMatterForm").submit();
}
});
```

Comment: okies! But your url must be pointing to /dashboard to work as you will be posting the data to the same form. If you don't want this restriction, you can use the approach as suggested and tested.